# Why is my query empty when I use a where/and filter casting getdate()

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, sql-server-2014, where-clause

I have a table with quite a few columns, one of those columns (ScheduleDate) is a date type column with the format of 2018-10-31 (YYYY-MM-DD). When I try to query the table filtering to show only entry's that are two days in the future, it comes back with no results

my code

```
SELECT
    ScheduleDate
  , Customer
  , Status
FROM SomeTable_1
WHERE Status = 'Pending'
AND ScheduleDate = CAST(GETDATE() + 2 AS DATE)
```

I've also tried formatting like this:

```
AND ScheduleDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() + 2)
```

I'm sure its a syntax error or something but SQL Server is just returning an empty result with the headers...

---

Turns out my Senior Dev was making changes to the table and deleted most of the records in the table, we only had records for next month. You all were correct that the records weren't there, I just hadn't refreshed my `SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE` results. I'm not sure why he didn't mention he had done this when I asked him why I was getting no results. Maybe he was pranking me. Thanks for all of your help, I'm going to go and hide in the corner now with a dunce cap on.

Comment: Are you positive that results exist where status = 'Pending' and scheduleDate is 2 days from now?

Comment: Yes, I have about 75 records per day for the next 30 days

Comment: `ScheduleDate` is an actual `DATE` column, not a `(N)VARCHAR` column with strings as dates?  Can you add sample data to the question?

Comment: You don't mean -2 do you? You specifically stated that have a value of `20181031` which is 2 days ago, not 2 days from now. Also, personally, I would use`DATEADD` over the ` +2` (`DATEADD(DAY,2,GETDATE())`)

Comment: Correct squillman, the column datatype is `DATE` I'm worried that there is just something wrong with my server because I feel like there's nothing wrong with my syntax...

Comment: @Larnu currently -2 or +2 doesn't matter, I'm doing testing and can't use today's date because all of those records get deleted by the current system I'm trying to replace, which is actually a big part of why I'm replacing the current program. Also because its a FoxPro program and nobody on the team has ever worked with it, or knows anything about it. It was written like 20 years ago haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `select getdate()` returns the correct value (i.e. your system clock is correct) then you either don't have any rows with that date, or the predicate `WHERE [Status] = 'Pending'` isn't resulting to TRUE for any rows.

This isn't reproducible with the given details.

```
declare @SomeTable_1 table (ScheduleDate date, Customer int, [Status] varchar(16))

insert into @SomeTable_1
values
('20181104',1,'Pending')

SELECT
    ScheduleDate
  , Customer
  , [Status]
FROM @SomeTable_1
WHERE [Status] = 'Pending'
AND ScheduleDate = CAST(GETDATE() + 2 AS DATE)
```

It also wouldn't matter if `ScheduleDate` was a `varchar` that would convert to a `date` for the equality operator.

```
declare @SomeTable_1 table (ScheduleDate varchar(16), Customer int, [Status] varchar(16))

insert into @SomeTable_1
values
('2018-11-04',1,'Pending')

SELECT
    ScheduleDate
  , Customer
  , [Status]
FROM @SomeTable_1
WHERE [Status] = 'Pending'
AND ScheduleDate = CAST(GETDATE() + 2 AS DATE)
```

**However, it would matter** if it was a `datetime` and the hour/minute/second wasn't 00:00:00

```
declare @SomeTable_1 table (ScheduleDate datetime, Customer int, [Status] varchar(16))

insert into @SomeTable_1
values
('20181104 13:24:00',1,'Pending')

SELECT
    ScheduleDate
  , Customer
  , [Status]
FROM @SomeTable_1
WHERE [Status] = 'Pending'
AND ScheduleDate = CAST(GETDATE() + 2 AS DATE)
```

Of note, you should really use [`dateadd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of the addition operator.

Comment: Thank you I'll look more in to that, I'm just using the addition operator for simplicity in testing, final product will be pulling that days results so it will be removed in production.

Comment: i edited the first line... make sure your system clock is correct by running `select getdate()`. If it is, then something doesn't make sense.

Comment: I feel like an idiot right now, thank you for your help.. please see my answer to the post below yours...